# Addressing parameter function's parameter in a scala method

Tags: scala

It's probably obvious, but it's making me crazy and I think my code is being bloated as a result (missing the obvious, not the *making me crazy part*).

I have a method as follows:

```
def fun(f: Int => Boolean, y: Int): Int
```

This method is going to be called like this `fun(*some anon func*, y)` and should increase and return y + 1 when *some anon function* (applied to some param) is greater than 0 and y - 1 otherwise. How to define `fun`? I'm trying something like

```
def fun(f: Int => Boolean, y: Int): Int = 
  if (f) y - 1
  else y + 1
```

Obviously, that doesn't work. I should put `f(tmp)`, where `tmp:Int` but I'm now sure how to express that.

All examples I could find online always apply `f` on `y`, but this is just funny.

Update: here's a similar problem I have already solved, but am not happy with **how did I do it**:

*For a given function `forall(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean`, which returns true iff all the set elements **x** in **S** (`def S: int => Boolean`, indicator function for set S) satisfy `p(x)`, create a function that will implement* **exists** *quantifier (`exists` function)*. In set theory, one can express this quantifier as (in terms of the problem described above) *not all elements (not forall) of a set satisfy NOT p*.

I did something like this:

```
def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
  def negP(x: Int): Boolean = !p(x)
  !forall(s, negP)
}
```

My question is: how to do this without defining `negP`? I cannot state `!p` because Scala gives error for `!` operator. I cannot use `!p(x)` because there is no `x`. Hence the problem above and my question.

TIA

Comment: Regarding `anon function is greater than 0` -- `f: Int => Boolean` cannot be compared to `0: Int`, so probably you should clarify your goals.

Comment: Your function f : what is the int parameter you want to call it with? If you already provide the value then it should not take a parameter

Comment: @dveim modified the question a bit. essentially, if I pass `(x: Int) => x * x`, then `y` would always go up, no matter what. However, when I pass `(x: Int) => x - 2`, it will get different results for x <= 2 and for x > 2.

Comment: @Ossip `fun` will work on a set of numbers, function I pass to it and some number `y` I send to it.

Comment: It feels like you don't know what you want to do rather than not knowing how to do it

Comment: @hummingBird In the question you say `fun` is "applied to some param" but there is no such param provided to `fun`.  Where does the param come from?

Comment: can you show the code calling it?

Comment: I'm afraid Dici was on the right track. It turns out I was wrong the whole time and my approach was wrong. It's still a bit fuzzy for me how to deal with certain things in Scala. This is part of the homework and I wanted to see how to overcame what I thought was my biggest obstacle. I will, however, update the question with something that depicts this problem and my own solution to it and would welcome anyone who could get a better one (my solution was accepted though).

Comment: @hummingBird -just to make sure, is it safe to assume that the Set in question can only contains Int? I only ask because scala.collection.set needs to be passed with a type parameter, like so:
`def exists[T](s: Set[T], p: Int => Boolean): Boolean`

Comment: yes, only int. For any int it gives True or false, also giving an answer whether or not the *int* is in the set or not.

Comment: @hummingBird I updated my answer, hope it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it return a function that does that, like so:

```
def fun(f: Int => Int, y: Int): Int => Int = 
input => if (f(input) > 0) y - 1 else y + 1


  val test1 = fun(x => x*2, 1)
  println(test1(-1))  // "2"
  val test2 = fun(x => x - 100, 5)
  println(test2(101)) // "4"
  val test3 = fun(x => x, -10)
  println(test3(0))  // "-9"
```

EDIT: Note that I changed the signature of the input function, as I think it probably reflects the requirements better, changing it back to boolean should be trivial(see other answers). :)

EDIT(2):
Seeing is you updated your question, I thought best to update my answer: You can always just inline a function, in your example, maybe you could do it like this:

```
def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = !forall(s, x => !p(x))
```

Comment: Although the OP didn't make what they wanted very clear, it seems like it could be the right answer

Comment: @Dici, you made it clear - you hate when people can't explain very well. What I did was giving an example and did my best to explain. Learning scala for the first time and also functional programming, certain concepts are giving me a headache since I don't know how to approach the problem. And to help - No, this doesn't resolve my answer. Thx for trying

Comment: @raudbjorn, unfortunately, this doesn't help because function signature has changed. Thx and sorry for issues in explaining. If it helps, I have Dici complaining about my issues in explaining to share some pain around :)

Comment: @hummingBird hum ? Hope it didn't come as aggressive, I wasn't particularly criticizing your question, just saying I was not sure what the exact requirements were although this answer seemed to meet them. Don't take things personally dude :p

Comment: @Dici i didn't in your first comment. i actually supported... just kinda minded when u started answering around to other ppl :P

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your original problem can't be solved because you can't test the output of `f()` without invoking `f()`, and you can't invoke `f()` without an input argument to pass. I think  the best you can hope for is something like this.

```
def fun(f: Int => Boolean, y: Int): Int => Int = (arg: Int) =>
  if (f(arg)) y - 1
  else        y + 1
```

---

Your "similar problem" looks to me like it should be a different question.

Your proposed solution can be solved via recursion, but using `forall()` it can be expressed more concisely.

```
def exists(s: Set[Int], p: Int => Boolean): Boolean =
  !forall(s, (x:Int) => !p(x))
```

Comment: Thx for you reply. It doesn't compile because I didn't expose foreach code. Essentially, that code uses recursion to iterate through all possible options and it was my goal - and task's goal to use foreach and some rules of first order logic to achieve the same goal. Just imagine that `foreach` is defined in a library and that it goes through all of the set elements and say if all of them satisfy the function `p: Int => Boolean`. Then exists can simply be resolved as NOT (FOREACH (P(X) == FALSE)) - not all of the elements give p(x) false

Comment: I agree ... I put it wrong and your updated answer does contain the solution I was looking for. I already accepted the answer though .. although both solutions give the same answer pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't actually want to pass a parameter to your anonymous function? Then try this:

```
def fun(f: () => Boolean, y: Int): Int = 
  if (f()) y - 1
  else y + 1
```